# What's the best way to check that the output is stable using junit?

Tags: junit4

I have a method which takes a data structure and writes to an OutputStream.  I'd like to write a unit test which ensures that the output of that function for a given input doesn't change unexpectedly.

I think I have the test structured the right way, using JUnit Theories. My @DataPoints are pairs of identifiers and example data structures, and I have an @Theory that the output from the method will be identical to a file checked in to version control that I fetch using getResourceAsStream using the identifier.

The painful part, however, is generating those files in the first place. My current very ugly solution is a boolean constant called WRITE_TEST_OUTPUT, which is usually false.  When I want to regenerate the output files (either because I've changed the list of @DataPoints or the desired behaviour of the method has changed) I set this constant to true, and there's a test which when this is true runs the function again to write the current output files to a directory in /tmp.  It then asserts that the constant is false, so I don't accidentally check in a version in which the constant is true.

It's very convenient to have the generation pretend to be a test so I can run it from within Eclipse, but it seems like a horrible kludge.  This seems like the sort of thing people must do all the time - what kind of solutions have other people found?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd probably do is detect the file's existence rather than use an externally modified constant. So you'd have something like

```
public void testMethodOutput() {
  if (new File(expectedOutput).exists()) {
    // check method output against file
  } else {
    // generate expected output from current behaviour; test passes automatically
    // (saves output to the expected-output file)
  }
}
```

When you want to update the expected output, delete the file, run tests, commit the new version to version control. No source change necessary.

It seems a little strange that the correct output is determined by looking at what a given version of the program does, rather than something you yourself set up (what if that version has a subtle bug?). Possibly that's a hint that your test is too coarse-grained, and that in turn might hint that your method is itself too coarse-grained. (Test smells are nearly always design smells.)

Comment: I'm not sure how the running test can figure out where it should save the file in a Maven module - getResource() will return a directory under target, not under src/test/resources.